# Alternative python modules to RDKit to convert SMILES to structure

Tags: molecular-structure, software, cheminformatics

Python module [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/) is great, but it cannot be installed by `pip`, and therefore it is difficult to use it sometimes in a virtual environment.

I am wondering that if there are some alternative python modules that can convert smiles to chemical structures?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use free software to convert SMILES strings to structures?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43299/is-there-a-way-to-use-free-software-to-convert-smiles-strings-to-structures)

Comment: @Mithoron, Thanks a lot for your kind help. These tools are not suitable for me. Except `Pysmiles`, the rest tools are not python-based. `Pysmiles` cannot convert smiles to chemical structures.

Comment: There is also the Indigo Toolkit. An example appears in an answer to this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94774/free-api-to-view-2d-representation-of-molecules/132932#132932).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61887/portable-library-to-render-2d-structural-formulas-as-vector-graphics-from-smiles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of any other Python tool not mentioned in the question @Mithoron linked to. [Openbabel](https://pypi.org/project/openbabel/) is available via pip by the way.

That RDKit is not available on PyPi should not hinder you from using it in a virtual environment. RDKit is available via the [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) package manager which is easy to use and combinable with pip.

If you are on Linux, the probably best solution for managing different versions of Python (also Anaconda Python) and virtual environments is [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I highly recommend to check it out.